# apache commons ftp doesn't work on release build apk

Tags: android, ftp, build.gradle, apache-commons, apache-ftpserver

I'm able to upload files to an FTP Server when I'm using a debug build, but it fails in the release build:

- it fails regardless if minify is enabled or not
- it fails even when I remove proguard settings

I am able to generate the release build apk with no errors. The upload-to-ftp feature in the app just won't work.

build.gradle

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'

....

minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
// proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
debuggable true
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keep class com.integratedbiometrics.** { *;}
-keep class org.libusb.** { *;}
-keep class com.futronictech.** { *;}
-keep class com.smufsbio.btsdk.** { *;}
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.compatibility.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add the full build.gradle if this is possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working already. I found out it was not the shrinking and obfuscating at all because setting `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to `true` in both release and debug build still gave me an issue with the release build while the debug build worked well.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

The only difference then was the signingConfig, and when I set
`signingConfig signingConfigs.release`
in the debug build, the problem surfaced in the debug build.

Apparently, there was something wrong with the security certificate I was signing the apk with. Creating a new certificate fixed the issue for me. It's the first release so there's no issue in doing so.